# Giving a PHP script root access to all files

Tags: php, macos, permissions

I want to read files from somewhere on my Mac (`Users/Me/Documents`) with `scandir` in PHP (XAMPP). However for this folder I get the error

```
Warning: scandir(/Users/Me/Documents):
Failed to open dir: Permissions denied in
-my script
```

I already `chown`ed it to root, and `get_current_user()` returns root, but I cannot seem to fix it. I also don't want to set permissions of the folder for everyone to read it, but rather permit the script to view every file. But none of the answers on the interwebs seems to provide a satisfactory answer.

EDIT: the relevant part of my code is this. It basically is a file navigator

```
            if (array_key_exists("path", $_GET)){
                $path = realpath($_GET["path"]);
            } else {
                $path = realpath("/..");
            }
            echo "<h1>$".basename($path)."/</h1>";
            echo '<div ID="fileTree">';
            foreach ( scandir ($path) as $dir) {
                if ($dir != '.'){

                    $class = "visible";

                    echo '<a ';

                    if ($dir[0] == "." && $dir != "..") {
                        $class = "hidden";
                    }

                    if ($dir == ".."){
                        $icon = "&#9650;";
                    } else if (is_dir($path.'/'.$dir)){
                        $icon = "&#9658;";
                    } else {
                        $icon = "&#x258B;";
                    }
                    echo 'class='.$class.' href=".?path='.$path;
                    if (is_dir(realpath($path.'/'.$dir))){
                        echo "/".$dir;
                    } else {
                        echo '&file='.$dir;
                    }
                    echo '" >'.$icon." ".$dir."</a>";
                }
            }
            echo "</div>";
```

Comment: If the script is running under your user account, it should have access.

Comment: You should never run PHP or the webserver as root. Make an user for both and run both under that user. Make for all files the user as owner and set the necessary permission. You could even chmod the files and directories to 777 to make sure everyone has access to them (read, write and execute).

Comment: @user261922 Right before the `scandir` what is the contents of `$path`, can you do an echo with your name redacted?

Comment: @user261922 Also on Mac with XAMPP, and I managed to get contents of my documents folder without having to `chmod` or `chown` anything in the past, therefore I believe there's something in the script causing the path to be incorrect.

Comment: @JamieBicknell works fine for all super folders

Comment: Oh right I see. In that case you want to open terminal, and use `chown` and `chmod` to recursively change ownership and permissions.